# mysql: natural join

Tags: mysql, sql

everyone! I'm currently trying to make a simple table with MySQL that satisfies the below condition.

> make a table of ship names, displacement, and numGuns with ones participated 'Guadalcanal' battle

[image]
[image]
[image]

3 tables are needed to make this.

I've tried several codes but they all failed.

I also wonder if I can use 'natural join' redundantly.

Here's the code I've been trying

```
#1st trial
select distinct ship as name, displacement, numGuns
from Ships natural join Classes
natural join Outcomes
where battle = 'Guadalcanal';

#2nd trial
select distinct ship as Name
from Outcomes natural join Ships
where battle = 'Guadalcanal'
union
select displacement, numGuns
from Classes
where name = Name and ??
```

I added data input query for the case you might need it.

Big Thanks beforehand!

```
create table Classes(
  Class varchar(20), type char(20), country varchar(20), numGuns int, bore int, displacement int,
  primary key(Class));

create table Ships(
 name varchar(20), Class varchar(20), launched int,
 primary key(name),
 foreign key(Class) references Classes (Class));

create table Outcomes(
 ship varchar(20), battle varchar(20), result varchar(10),
 foreign key(battle) references Battles(Name),
 foreign key(ship) references Ships(name));

insert into Classes values 
('Bismark', 'bb', 'Germany', 8, 15, 42000),
('Iowa', 'bb', 'USA', 9, 16, 46000),
('Kongo', 'bc', 'Japan', 8, 14, 32000),
('North Carolina', 'bb', 'USA', 9, 16, 37000),
('Renown', 'bc', 'Gt. Britain', 6, 15, 32000),
('Revenge', 'bb', 'Gt. Britain', 8,15, 29000),
('Tennessee', 'bb', 'USA', 12, 14, 32000),
('Yamato', 'bb', 'Japan', 9, 18, 65000);

insert into Ships values
('Prince of Wales', 'Tennessee', 1921),
('Bismark', 'Bismark', 1915),
('Duke of York', 'Kongo', 1914),
('Iowa', 'Iowa', 1943),
('Kirishima', 'Kongo', 1915),
('Kongo', 'Kongo', 1913),
('Fuso', 'Iowa', 1943),
('Yamashiro', 'Yamato', 1942),
('California', 'Iowa', 1943),
('North Carolina', 'North Carolina', 1941),
('Renown', 'Renown', 1916),
('Hood', 'Renown', 1916),
('Scharnhorst', 'Revenge', 1916),
('Revenge', 'Revenge', 1916),
('King George V', 'Revenge', 1916),
('South Dakota', 'Revenge', 1916),
('Tennessee', 'Tennessee', 1920),
('Washington', 'North Carolina', 1941),
('West Virginia', 'Iowa', 1943),
('Yamato', 'Yamato', 1941);

insert into Outcomes values 
('Bismark', 'North Atlantic', 'sunk'),
('California', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok'),
('Duke of York', 'North Cape', 'ok'),
('Duke of York', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok'),
('Fuso', 'Surigao Strait', 'sunk'),
('Hood', 'North Atlantic', 'sunk'),
('King George V', 'North Atlantic', 'ok'),
('Kirishima', 'Guadalcanal', 'sunk'),
('Prince of Wales', 'North Atlantic', 'damaged'),
('Prince of Wales', 'North Cape', 'ok'),
('Scharnhorst', 'North Cape', 'sunk'),
('South Dakota', 'Guadalcanal', 'damaged'),
('Tennessee', 'Surigao Strait', 'sunk'),
('Washington', 'Guadalcanal', 'ok'),
('West Virginia', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok'),
('Yamashiro', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok');
```

Comment: I think if you never use natural join, you'll manage just fine

Comment: You'll also survive without `,` comma joins. `JOIN  .. ON` or `JOIN ... USING` are the safe ones for most common uses. General problem with natural joins is someone adds a table of a specific name and it magically becomes a join criteria in the query and this may not be desired.

Comment: Similarly with USING. I find USING confUSING. But each to their own.

Comment: I agree that you should just **never** use natural joins. They must have been drunk when they invented them.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This was my first time trying sql. had no idea what to use. Thank you for your advise!! I'll keep in mind

Comment: @Strawberry: With `USING` you state the columns at least. They can make joins on tables with composite keys more readable and less error-prone (`from a join b using (x,y,z)` is easier to read than `from a join b on b.x=a.x and b.y=a.y and b.z=b.z` and cannot contain the mistake the latter contains). And I like `USING` with full outer joins sometimes, because you don't need `COALESCE` to display the joined key. But, yes, generally I, too, prefer `ON` over `USING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show data of two tables: `ships` and `classes` they are 1:n related, so just join them (`inner join on / using`). Then you have the condition to only consider ships that partcipated in a particular battle. Conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause ideally. We look up data in other tables with `EXISTS` or `IN`.

```
select s.name, c.numguns, c.displacement
from ships s
join classes c on c.class = s.class
where s.name in (select ship from outcomes where battle = 'Guadalcanal')
order by s.name;
```

By putting the condition in the `WHERE` clause we avoid getting any duplictates. Well, in this case (only one battle) we wouldn't get duplicates anyway, but consider looking at more than one battle. A join would give us the ships multifold, as a join sais "give me the ships combined with their battles", while `IN` and `WHERE` just say "give me the ships when they participated in at least one of the battles".

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
SELECT Ships.name, Classes.displacement, Classes.numGuns 
FROM Ships 
INNER JOIN Classes ON Ships.Class = Classes.Class
INNER JOIN Outcomes ON Outcomes.Ship = Ships.Name
WHERE Outcomes.battle = 'Guadalcanal';
```

If you need any help please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried, but I got an error described as "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Outcomes.battle' in 'where clause'" It's weird, because I can clearly see the point of your code line and thought this would work!

Comment: You forgot to join `outcomes` it seems :-)

Comment: Sorry, you must be kidding - a 1980s-style cross join? On one hand this syntax is awfully outdated and on the other you'd want an inner join, not a cross join.

Comment: As this was still wrong, I thought instead of downvoting I should better just put in the missing join. I've edited this answer accordingly. Please also see that proper formatting helps reading a query.